# Однокоренные ли слова "простота" и "просторечие"?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова, морфемика

Можно ли назвать простое и сложное (двухкорневое) слово однокоренными? 
Если нет, то какое существует для таких случаев название?

Например:

простота и просторечие;

миро и мироточение;

благо и благословение

Answer (score 2):

Однокоренные слов — те, в которых есть один и тот же корень. Если в слове два, три — сколько угодно корней, среди которых есть X, то любое другое слово с корнем X будет однокоренным.

И **мир**о, и **мир**оточить; и **благ**о, и **благ**ословение; и **прост**ота, и **прост**оречие — однокоренные слова.